# Insert Ad Code in the Middle of a Post

Tags: functions, the-content

I want to insert an ad code in the middle of a post via `functions.php`.

I found several links but either they don't use `functions.php` or don't insert the code in the middle.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Also, I don't want to use a plugin.

Comment: No research efforts, no reason for _no plugin_, not even your own code … please invest more time into your question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This function inserts your ad code after the specified paragraph.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_ad_content');

function wpse_ad_content($content)
{
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 2; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '<div style="width: 300px; height: 250px; padding: 6px 6px 6px 0; float: left; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 18px;">';
            $new_content.= '//Enter your ad code here....';
            $new_content.= '</div>';
        }

        $new_content.= $content[$i] . "</p>";
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

Comment: @Programmer : & I want a Ferrari this christmas..! . . . . . . . $paragraphAfter = count(it)/2 !!

Comment: If there is only one paragraph, the ad will not be displayed.

Comment: This worked very well. I used it to insert a shortcode for a slider that appears after X paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives:

First, you can use shortcodes as @iambriansreed suggest, but you need to know PHP programming to register the shortcode. The following code is [from a website (in spanish)](http://ayudawordpress.com/insertar-adsense-con-shortcodes/) that shows how to program a simple shortcode with Adsense:

```
/* 
 * Copy the code into your theme's functions.php file
 * Change the AdSense <script> for yours 
 */
function showads() {
    return '<div><script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    google_ad_slot = "4668915978";
    google_ad_width = 468;
    google_ad_height = 60;
    //-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>';
}

add_shortcode('adsense', 'showads');
```

Second, you can use a plugin like [Quick Adsense](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-adsense/) to achieve the same shortcode but easily customizable or let the plugin select where to put the ads.

And finally, you can write your own code to add ads at n-th paragraph (i.e. exploiting each paragraph and selecting the n-th paragraph and add there your ads code). It's not the best solution but it will be fully customizable.